# ASP dotnet core web app container running but not opening in browser. using .net 6.0

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

ASP dotnet core web app container running but not opening in browser. using .net 6.0

i tried http://localhot
container port. please let me know where i am doing mistake.

Below i am sharing my Dockerfile and docker inpect result.

```
#workdir consider in app folder
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
#restoring nuget package for csproj files
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
#copy all project files
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
#creating running image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out/ .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","dotnetpracticeapp2.dll"]
```

Docker container inspect output
11:11
my dotnet core web .net 6.0 version Container is running but not opening in browser,here is my some details

```
#workdir consider in app folder
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
#restoring nuget package for csproj files
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
#copy all project files
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
#creating running image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out/ .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","dotnetpracticeapp2.dll"]
```

Docker container inspect output

```
  {
        "Id": "9fc1f41590c7e25ddd5ec66c542afac89c00ee9cef9c5148368f39c8a04248ce",
        "Created": "2022-03-11T17:24:11.7749279Z",
        "Path": "dotnet",
        "Args": [
            "dotnetpracticeapp2.dll"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 1304,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-03-12T18:00:28.6816882Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2022-03-12T17:55:41.1098514Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:7d342807b790f1c7a2470db3ae47a85849bd8354939c3e4659a24d1ee388799f",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9fc1f41590c7e25ddd5ec66c542afac89c00ee9cef9c5148368f39c8a04248ce/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9fc1f41590c7e25ddd5ec66c542afac89c00ee9cef9c5148368f39c8a04248ce/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9fc1f41590c7e25ddd5ec66c542afac89c00ee9cef9c5148368f39c8a04248ce/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/9fc1f41590c7e25ddd5ec66c542afac89c00ee9cef9c5148368f39c8a04248ce/9fc1f41590c7e25ddd5ec66c542afac89c00ee9cef9c5148368f39c8a04248ce-json.log",
        "Name": "/dotnetapp2",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                16,
                125
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5c6af7c62a17860faa1bccd6d57b064bc9639fbdc06dc200f12c63f0743fb0b7-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2fgcm3ps2hi5wuzj4nmid1gj4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7g09cyks1ftmankkfn8rytjea/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/43fbef426074496a5423ec4f2423857878095a252a5091db78cfe891af95ed3d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dbf0cc5fcf1324ccac8470143b6b87a313e4df9a9aa344a9e600c968afcafa16/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/41d81ab7ea010ecb9fac87a3b63d7183228ffc286bb2063690e5f7169f212d20/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ee4f5439a2a5103f23ade1cde12fcf6ca386e1f2affbbd9337769ef1ef0ecd4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/15bdfbb6aecdf14bbe0b554c229ef08c4bd578c0ac2c6c002c419344d198df1a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f8e7d9c155d0f25cd0076112aa911496febe9ca4e7a9ace2bf7a09b80f0c0bd5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e1c521705e01879f23dadea31f56fb5ad6693acc5ddacec190216556cb8ba742/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/095c04af29c37be9e84dbba0d0b7aadf6c0c91fbeca2a2fa1843815b0ebf9cd0/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5c6af7c62a17860faa1bccd6d57b064bc9639fbdc06dc200f12c63f0743fb0b7/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5c6af7c62a17860faa1bccd6d57b064bc9639fbdc06dc200f12c63f0743fb0b7/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5c6af7c62a17860faa1bccd6d57b064bc9639fbdc06dc200f12c63f0743fb0b7/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "9fc1f41590c7",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": true,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS=",
                "DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true",
                "DOTNET_VERSION=6.0.3",
                "ASPNET_VERSION=6.0.3",
                "Logging__Console__FormatterName=",
                "DOTNET_GENERATE_ASPNET_CERTIFICATE=false",
                "DOTNET_NOLOGO=true",
                "DOTNET_SDK_VERSION=6.0.201",
                "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true",
                "NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip",
                "POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL=PSDocker-DotnetSDK-Debian-11"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "parshchakurkar/dotnetapp:1.21",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "dotnet",
                "dotnetpracticeapp2.dll"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "1788646d554f21bfed7a1c0be2c884f136bd7095aee00b10f36f1ce155225bc6",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/1788646d554f",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "53d78ef8e764106367138ca777d419035a03219570a0a523875cf7157a8cd299",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "464a5c9c0dcba8adc13abe8ef9c2d4756a4b1525a92bfe643b4e2ef75b609d57",
                    "EndpointID": "53d78ef8e764106367138ca777d419035a03219570a0a523875cf7157a8cd299",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

please check and update where i am doing mistake

Comment: if it is possible try to avoid using 80 port, This is because 80 is the default port, and it was taken by other processes.

Comment: *i tried http://localhot* -- please fix the typo.

Comment: what is the out of  docker logs <<your container ids>>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume docker command "**docker run --rm -it -p 80:80 image ID**"

Map port 80 on the local machine to port 80 in the container.

Please in the Internet browser key `http://localhost: you build port 80 (EXPOSE 80)`

if is in dockerfile add `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80`

Please in the Internet browser key `http://0.0.0.0:80/`

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Thank you its working now , is this ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 necessary for asp dotnet 6.0

Comment: if Environment variables no parameter `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80` the Dockerfiles set the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` environment variable to listen on port 80.
but NET Core uses two types of Environment variables `DOTNET_URLS、ASPNETCORE_URLS`
because ASPNETCORE_URLS/DOTNET_URLS environment variables are most useful for setting the values in the production  Reference:https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/#comment-4889659188

Comment: can you try no  ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 and have ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 
run on docker image inspect [imageid] search ASPNETCORE_URLS difference